# sql add column with variable names

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there any way to add variable number of columns to a table.

I am trying below but no success.

```
DECLARE @VAR INT = 1
WHILE @VAR <=20
BEGIN
    DECLARE @COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX) = 'COLUMN_'+CAST(@VAR AS VARCHAR)
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYS.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('MY_TBL') AND name=@COLUMN )
        begin
        ALTER TABLE MY_TBL ADD @COLUMN NVARCHAR(3) NULL;
        end
    SET @VAR += 1
END
```

Comment: That's a *really* bad table design. Why are you embedding *data* in the *metadata* (column names). It will also lead to convoluted and confusing queries. The *standard* way of representing repeating groups of the same "type" of data is as multiple *rows* of data.

Comment: This is bad design. If you have lots of columns with the same type data, make multiple rows instead. Thats what they're for.

Comment: Summing up with previous guys here. This is a terrible design.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And yes this is a horrible idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL.
Try the following code.

```
DECLARE @VAR INT = 1
WHILE @VAR <=20
BEGIN
    DECLARE @COLUMN VARCHAR(MAX) = 'COLUMN_'+CAST(@VAR AS VARCHAR)
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM SYS.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('MY_TBL') AND name=@COLUMN )
        begin
        declare @sql varchar(100)= ' ALTER TABLE MY_TBL ADD '+@COLUMN+' NVARCHAR(3) NULL;' 
        exec(@sql);
        end
    SET @VAR += 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-Server:

Format:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'database' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'table'
```

Example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'imDB' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'MovieName'
```

You can store it in a variable and use it accordingly.

I hope you understood :)

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: I don't know what was in his mind when he wrote this answer 6 year ago.