# Add column with name of variable value

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure, temp-tables, alter

Inside procedure, I want to create a temporary table "report" with column names of another table "descriptions" rows contents, but I get error, because my query instead of using variable "tmp_description" value, uses its name to create a new column. How to use variable value as name for the new column?

```
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tmp_description varchar(30);

...

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE descriptions (description varchar(30));

insert into descriptions
        select distinct description from pure;
    
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM descriptions;
            SET i=0;
            WHILE i<n DO 
                SELECT * INTO tmp_description FROM (SELECT * FROM descriptions LIMIT i,1) t1;
                ALTER TABLE report
                ADD COLUMN 
                    tmp_description FLOAT(2) DEFAULT 0.0;          <-- I get error here
                SET i = i + 1;
            END WHILE;
```

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL with the `PREPARE` statement.

Comment: Have you read this? [References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43247103/sql-add-column-with-variable-names/43247232)

Comment: @MuhKandaWibawaPutra, no, thank you

Comment: @MuhKandaWibawaPutra Another DBMS, won't help (except the fact that dynamic SQL needed).

Comment: @Akina, as I said in the question, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any value to doing this in a `while` loop.  Your looping mechanism is all off anyway, because you are using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` -- which means that the row returned on each iteration is arbitrary.

Why not just construct a single statement?  First run:

```
select group_concat('add column ', description, ' numeric(2)' separator ', ') as columns
from t;
```

Note that `float(2)` doesn't really make sense to me as a data type.  I suspect that you really want a `numeric`/`decimal` type.

Then take the results.  Prepend them with `alter table report`  and run the code.

You could do this using dynamic SQL, but I see no advantage to doing that.